# UIPickerView only populates with "?"

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm trying to populate my two pickerViews from arrays, but only coming up with "?" I've tried some of the fixes for similar types on here but none of them have worked.

```
    @IBOutlet var startPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var endPickerView: UIPickerView!
    var startPickerData: [Int] = []
    var endPickerData: [Int] = []
    let startArray = (1...999).map { $0 }
    let endArray = (2...1000).map { $0 }

    let startPickerCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)
    let endPickerCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 2)

    var isStartPickerShown: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            startPickerView.isHidden = !isStartPickerShown
        }
    }
    var isEndPickerShown: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            endPickerView.isHidden = !isEndPickerShown
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.startPickerView.delegate = self
        self.startPickerView.dataSource = self
        self.endPickerView.delegate = self
        self.endPickerView.dataSource = self
        startPickerData = startArray
        endPickerData = endArray

        self.startPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        self.endPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath {
        case startPickerCellIndexPath:
            if isStartPickerShown {
                return 216.0
            } else {
                return 0.0
            }
        case endPickerCellIndexPath:
            if isEndPickerShown {
                return 216.0
            } else {
                return 0.0
            }
            default:
            return 44.0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        switch indexPath {
        case startPickerCellIndexPath:

            if isStartPickerShown {
                isStartPickerShown = false
            } else if isStartPickerShown {
                isStartPickerShown = false
                isStartPickerShown = true
            } else {
                isStartPickerShown = true
            }

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()

        case endPickerCellIndexPath:
            if isEndPickerShown {
                isEndPickerShown = false
            } else if isEndPickerShown {
                isEndPickerShown = false
                isEndPickerShown = true
            } else {
                isEndPickerShown = true
            }

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()  
            default:
            break
        }
    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return startPickerData.count
        } else {
            return endPickerData.count
        }
    }

    // The data to return fopr the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int? {
        let startView: Int = startPickerData[row]
        let endView: Int = endPickerData[row]

        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return startView
        } else {
        return endView
        }
    }
}
```

I've been working on this for a day and a half and haven't been able to figure out why it won't work and I've already tried several fixes from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your private method at the very bottom to this:

```swift
    // The data to return fopr the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let startView: Int = startPickerData[row]
        let endView: Int = endPickerData[row]
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return String(format: "%d", startView)
        } else {
            return String(format: "%d", endView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: That got it to work, thank you very much! Is it just that the pickerView won't display Int dat types?

Comment: No problem! the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol requires that method to return a `String?` type, so you have to parse the `Int` value into a `String`. Please feel free to upvote my answer and mark it correct as soon as you are able.

Comment: I upvoted but it won't show because I have 0 reputation, and marked as correct.

Comment: Great! Welcome to StackOverflow